# Use local var outside of function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will someone please show me how to use a local var outside the local scope?

```
function dosomething(e) { 
    current = jQuery(e);
    currentStartDate = current.datepicker('getDate');
    newStartDate = Date.parse(currentStartDate) / 1000;
}; 

newDate = null;
     jQuery(".gform_wrapper li input#input_2_1").change(function() {
             newDate = dosomething(this); 
});

// Use newDate here
```

Comment: You *can* use `newDate` wherever you want.  The problem is that it's not *set* until *after* this `onchange` event runs.

Comment: newDate will be set to the 'dosomething(e) function' because you're not returning anything from the function. Your 'dosomething(e)' needs to have a 'return newStartDate;'

Comment: @Rocket - That seems to be the problem, if there is a way around that, I'd appreciate an example! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: How are you trying to access `newDate`?  What exactly are you trying to do?  You might need to move that code *inside* the `change()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it outside the local scope, unless it is assigned to the global scope. If it doesn,t exist though, Javascript will automatically add a global scope variable with the name, but is a weird occurrence and most of the time not meant by the programmer. Use strict to stop that. Anyways, you have to assign it to the global scope, and set in local scope.

```
function dosomething(e) { 
    current = jQuery(e);
    currentStartDate = current.datepicker('getDate');
    newStartDate = Date.parse(currentStartDate) / 1000;
}; 



---> VAR  newDate = null;
         jQuery(".gform_wrapper li input#input_2_1").change(function() {
                 newDate = dosomething(this); 
    });
```

You just needed to add var in this case. Then you can use it outside the scope.

Comment: Did I not assign it globally when I set newDate = null?

Comment: Thank you for catching that Casey.

Comment: No problem. Javascript is awesome, but can be a pain.